# Why is Spearman's rank $n-2$ degrees of freedom?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, correlation

I have a basic understanding of degrees of freedom but I get lost when it's about Spearman's. Every book says $n-2$ however my understanding would mean it is either $n-1$ or $2(n-1)$ but is isn't. How so?

Comment: Please explain in details what you are looking for. Are you looking for distribution of Spearman rank correlation?

Comment: When we do a Spearmans rank correllation coefiicient and we want to test for significance, we take the degrees of freedom to be n-2, but why?

Comment: To understand why the null distribution of Spearman's rank correlation follows t-distribution  with degrees of freedom (n-2), you have understand what determine the degrees of freedom in sampling distributions. Here the t distribution has degrees of freedom 2 less than the number of sample observation because of two constraints. Can follow https://www.jstor.org/stable/2285508?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents